# How can i fix display plot of loss validation

Tags: python, keras

I have problem with display plot
Loss and validation accuracy
I tray same code many time and give me good result with different model
But know i run i faced this problem but iam not change any thing i restart golab and creat new opennotebook but same problem , also the same code with same model before give me good plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlCQ9.jpg)

I suppose fine slution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.